# API vs. the Cached Web

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I am working on a site where the pages are HTML and they interact with the server using Ajax calls. This works great - the pages are responsive and page loads are minimized.

What's the best way to deal with a cached HTML page when the API has changed?
Tell the pages to never cache? This would work, but it would slow things down.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "when the API is changed", but you can always bypassing caching when you change a resource by changing the name of the resource (e.g. incrementing a number in the filename) so that it can't possibly be in the cache.  In this manner, you can have long caching and immediate update for new resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want something to be cached, don't let it be cached.  This won't slow things down for most applications in the way you describe... you're only loading that page once per session.

Another thing to worry about is what to do when a user has the page up but the backend server has been updated.  A common method is for the client to include a version parameter with its requests.  The API can then request the client to reload if a newer version is available.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing something similar to this that is working well. When a page is first loaded, I pass the client's version to the server. If the server reports back that the version is old, the client clears the page and tells the user that they are looking at a cached page and asks them to refresh their browser.

Comment: @DougJohnson How will users already on your site know if there is a new version?

Comment: @DougJohnson Right, but I'm suggesting that perhaps you will have users on your site at the same time you want to do an upgrade.  The page is already loaded for them, and in the middle of the session they may go from one API version to the other.  If you send the version with your requests, the API server can return an error if there is a version mismatch, which can be handled client-side to automatically refresh the page (or prompt the user to do so).

Comment: Sorry, got messed up half way through typing the last comment. 

The client version is stored in a JavaScript file.
The expected client version is stored on the server.

When the page loads, it sends the client version to the server.

If these values don't match, the page is cleared and replaced with something:
This appears to be an older cached page.
Please refresh [Refresh]

There's no upgrade involved for the user. They just need to refresh, and this lets them know that they need to do so.